# Who is responsible for deleting the facet?

Tags: c++, c++11, locale

I have a function that uses the Boost.DateTime library for generating the current GMT/UTC date and time string ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=92230ebf4090c76339ce86ae8d5ead19-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)).

```
std::string get_curr_date() {
    auto date = boost::date_time::second_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::universal_time();

    boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT");

    std::ostringstream os;
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), facet));
    os << date;

    return os.str();
}
```

This is mostly based on [Boost.DateTime's example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html):

```
//example to customize output to be "LongWeekday LongMonthname day, year"
//                                  "%A %b %d, %Y"
date d(2005,Jun,25);
date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%A %B %d, %Y"));
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
std::cout << d << std::endl;
// "Saturday June 25, 2005"
```

My code worked nicely, but now I'm feeling uneasy because of these particular lines containing `new`:

- `boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT");`
- `date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%A %B %d, %Y"));`

As you can see, there is no `delete` in Boost.DateTime's so I somehow presumed that it is imperative for me to `delete` the `date_facet`. I used `std::unique_ptr` to wrap the `new`ed `time_facet` object.

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::posix_time::time_facet> facet(new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"));
```

However, I am getting segfault errors, as you can see in [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=212ceaaedd5104de70130e2b289261e2-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). I have also tried manually `delete`ing the `new`ed pointer, and am still getting the same errors (sorry, can't reproduce error in Coliru).

The `time_facet` pointer is passed as an argument when constructing an `std::locale` object, so I'm confused who's the one responsible for `delete`ing the facet.

So here is the core of my question:

- **Am I required to `delete` the `time_facet`** or is the `std::locale` object responsible for `delete`ing it?

---

Please note that `boost::posix_time::time_facet` is derived from `boost::date_time::date_facet` which is, in turn, derived from `std::locale::facet`. This question might generalized to `std::locale::facet`, though my problem is specific to `time_facet`.

Here are some docs on `std::locale`'s constructors:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4121792d.aspx)
- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Am I required to delete the time_facet or is the std::locale object
>   responsible for deleteing the it?

You're not required to delete the `time_facet` so long as `time_facet` derives from `std::locale::facet`, which it should. The `std::locale::facet` is a base class that all facets should derive from that implement a form of reference counting. The standard says this:

§ 22.3.1.6

> Once a facet reference is obtained from a locale object by calling
>   `use_facet<>`, that reference remains usable, and the results from
>   member functions of it may be cached and re-used, as long as some
>   locale object refers to that facet.

Once all references of the facet are not being used, the destructor of `std::locale` will manage and delete references to the facet if its ref count is 0.

This is all specified in §22.3.1.1.2 in the C++11 standard. Where it states:

> The refs argument to the constructor is used for lifetime management.
>
> — For `refs == 0`, the implementation performs `delete
>   static_cast<locale::facet*>(f)` (where f is a pointer to the facet)
>   when the last locale object containing the facet is destroyed; for
>   `refs == 1`, the implementation never destroys the facet.

Answer (score 6):

Not answering your question as others have already done it. But, it's really not required to construct the locale everytime.

```
std::string get_curr_date_time() {
    namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;
    namespace bdt = boost::date_time;
    std::ostringstream os;
    auto date = bdt::second_clock<bpt::ptime>::universal_time();
    const static std::locale currlocale (os.getloc(), new bpt::time_facet("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"));
    boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT");

    os.imbue(currlocale);
    os << date;
    return os.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The locale is responsible for deleting the facet.

Comment: It means that the locale can't be declared as 'const static' ?