# std::locale take ownership

Tags: c++, std

I have the next code:

```
 boost::posix_time::time_facet facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%f");
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), &facet));
```

And when I run the this code it looks like compiler try to free the `facet` during `ss` destructor call (debuger says it).

When I run this code:

```
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%f")));
```

all right.

So, I wonder if exists any documentation about this behavior or reason why `local` takes ownership. I've tried to find out the explanation but there is nothing in the documentation.

Does `std::locale()` take ownership of time_facet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who is responsible for deleting the facet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779660/who-is-responsible-for-deleting-the-facet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

`template< class Facet >
locale( const locale& other, Facet* f );                       (7)`

> Overload 7 is typically called with its second argument, f, obtained directly from a new-expression: the locale is responsible for calling the matching delete from its own destructor.

There is also another hint about this in http://eel.is/c++draft/locale.facet#3:

> The refs argument to the constructor is used for lifetime management.
>   For refs == 0, the implementation performs delete static_­cast(f) (where f is a pointer to the facet) when the last locale object containing the facet is destroyed; for refs == 1, the implementation never destroys the facet.

It follows that there is an internal refcounting mechanism in `facet` (and derived classes). This more or less implies that the `facet` you pass to `locale` is shared with it and, if you do not explicitly increase its reference count, will be destroyed with it, since passing a pointer to it cannot increase the refcount.